# Detect keyboard layout in *nix in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, posix, keyboard-events

I am using [pykeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page) and want to extend it a little bit by adding information about current keyboard layout selected (right now you know from log what buttons are pressed assuming US `qwerty`).

For windows system it is looks like:

```
def get_locale(self):
        if os.name == 'nt':
            w = user32.GetForegroundWindow() 
            tid = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(w, 0) 
            return hex(user32.GetKeyboardLayout(tid))
```

to get hex code of layout (like 0x409409) that is fine for me as I basically want to distinguish one layout from another.

I would appreciate if you give me a solution for posix (for example ubuntu) system.

Comment: Try `/etc/default/keyboard/`

Comment: @DanielB do you mean that I can read from /etc/default/keyboard and thus get layout for current application in focus? For me `sudo cat /etc/default/keyboard` command returns same content for any current layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found following that works for me:

1. compiled [xkblayout-state](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state) and moved executable to directory in PATH
2. rewrote `get_locale` as

```
import os
if os.name == 'posix':    
    from subprocess import check_output
elif os.name == 'nt':
    import win32api, win32con, win32process
    from ctypes import windll
    user32 = windll.user32

def get_locale(self):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        w = user32.GetForegroundWindow() 
        tid = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(w, 0) 
        return hex(user32.GetKeyboardLayout(tid))
    elif os.name == 'posix':
        return check_output(["xkblayout-state", "print", "%s"])
```

and now `get_locale` returns nice letter code of current locale (i.e. 'us' for qwerty) in Ubuntu.

Yes, output is different in each OS and I will definitely rewrite this function in the future. But for now I have achieved my goal to be able to detect keyboard layout at windows and unix machines.

Another option is to use `xset` utility like `xset -q | grep -A 0 'LED' | cut -c59-67` (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/how-do-i-get-current-keyboard-layout) for details) but I think that it's little bit fishy especially if you have more than two layouts (like I do) - scroll LED is on for all except default layout.

Answer (score 2):

setxkbmap -print

```
xkb_keymap {
xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
xkb_symbols   { include "pc+gb+gr(simple):2+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"   };
xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(**qwerty**)" };

xkb_symbols   { include "pc+**gb**+ **gr**
(simple):2+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"    };

Comment: yes `setxkbmap -print` gives me the list of installed layouts but how can I detect which one is active right now?

Comment: if you want to know whats actice right now you can use xkb-switch. [link](https://github.com/ierton/xkb-switch). example:  
xkb-switch --> gr(simple), xkb-switch --> gb

Comment: well its not in python but you can make a small script that wgets it untars it cd in it and build it. then you can popen call it. not sure if thats the best solution but it will work.